# Return value for String method

Tags: java

Im just starting out with java and so I am writing some simple programs to learn the basics. I was wondering what return type to use for my takeNames method? I know it has to return a string so I use "" so that the user cant see anything.

This is one of my first programs so I think I must be doing something wrong, or maybe not wrong but my code could definitely be more efficient.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name{

  String fName;
  String lName;
  String line = takeNames(fName, lName);

  public String takeNames(String fName, String lName){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    fName = scanner.next();
    lName = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);
    return "";
  }


  public static void main(String [] args){
    Name l = new Name();
    System.out.println(l.line);


  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me if what I am using for a return statement is acceptable? Or could someone tell me a better more efficent way to write my code?
Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to return a string?

Comment: The answer is, what do you want the method to return?

Comment: I didnt see anyone else point this out, but it is worth mentioning that `return "";` is a valid statement in general, its just not what you should use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return anything.

```
public void takeNames(String fName, String lName){
```

Call it like this (replace your `main` method with this):

```
Name l = new Name();
l.takeNames();
```

And remove the line:

```
String line = takeNames(fName, lName);
```

which is then useless.

If you want to use `System.out.println(l.line)`, then try:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
fName = scanner.next();
lName = scanner.next();
return "Hello " + fName + " " + lName;
// can also be String.format("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the return type `void` if you don't want to return anything, like so -

```
public void takeNames(String fName, String lName){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
fName = scanner.next();
lName = scanner.next();
System.out.printf("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);//note no return statement needed!


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You later print out the return value of this method with `System.out.println(l.line)`, so maybe you want to return the string you print out in this method, instead of printing it out.

```
public String takeNames(String fName, String lName){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    fName = scanner.next();
    lName = scanner.next();
    return String.format("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.linkage.test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name{


  public static String takeNames(){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    String fName;
    String lName;
    fName = scanner.next();
    lName = scanner.next();

    System.out.printf("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);
    return fName+"_"+lName;
  }


  public static void main(String [] args){
      String[] arrays = takeNames().split("_");
      System.out.println();
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(arrays[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a `return` statement is to return something that will be useful later. Unless printing out a blank line, like `System.out.println(l.line);` will do, is useful to you, there's no point in doing that particular `return` statement.

The bigger issue is your code structure. Change it to this:

```
String fName;
String lName;
//Get rid of line

public void takeNames(){ //You don't need fName or lName in this line, since they're part of the object's fields
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    fName = scanner.next();
    lName = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Hello %s %s", fName, lName);
}


public static void main(String [] args){
    Name l = new Name();
    //What should you call here to get the same effect as before? Will let you figure that out
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this would be

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name{

  String fName;
  String lName;
  String fullName;

  public String takeNames(){ // don't need parameters else it will shadow above variables   

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    fName = scanner.next();
    lName = scanner.next();

    return fName + lName; // return full name 
  }


  public static void main(String [] args){
    Name l = new Name();
    fullName= l.takeNames(); // assign fullName returned from takeNames()
    System.out.println(fullName); // print


  }
}
```